# Using remove_autop on multiple specific pages within function.php of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to remove the inputted BR tag from specific pages within Wordpress. I do not wish to make this site wide as it is quite useful for the WP user.

I am trying to adapt some php I found, but I am not implementing the multiple pages aspect correctly. The code I am using currently is:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_autop', 9);
function remove_autop($content) {
if ( is_page ( ‘225’, ‘355’, ‘227’, ‘238’, ‘358’, ‘236’, ‘252’, ‘363’, ‘254’, ‘258’, ‘381’, ‘256’ ) ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
}
return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_35443518_remove_autop_for_postid', 0 );

function wpse_35443518_remove_autop_for_postid( $content )
{
    # edit the post id's
    $remove_from_postid = array('1','2','3');
    if(in_array(get_the_ID(), $remove_from_postid)) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, this does not work, but I noticed you have used post ids rather then page ids?

Comment: because pages are a post type and have postid :)